# Converting an expression: from angular frequency to Laplace variable $\ s =j \omega$

Tags: laplace-transform, education

I have the expression:

$$Z=\frac{A}{\sqrt{\omega}}+\frac{A}{j\sqrt{\omega}}$$

$$Z=A \sqrt{\frac{j}{s}}+\frac{A}{j}\sqrt{\frac{j}{s}}$$

I'm trying to get an expression with s variable, but it is very difficult. Can someone help me please?

If in the expression there are both s and j (e.g. $ 1+js$), is it right?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: substitute $$\omega=\dfrac{s}{j}$$can you finish now?

Comment: Hello @MostafaAyaz, I followed your hint. Is an expression with s and j correct?

Comment: Sure! Why not? If your inverse Laplace function intrinsically contains $j$ you have no other option for example take $x(t)=ju(t)$ where $u(t)$ is the step function. The Laplace transform would then be $$\dfrac{j}{s}$$which contains both $s,j$

Comment: Thank you for your hint @MostafaAyaz.

Comment: You're welcome! Hope it helps...